# Xcode: "Spurious Update" console warning?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm writing a pretty straightforward ObjC app. (The only minor complexity is that it uses an external library called Chilkat for some basic networking, but I don't think that that's relevant.)

Occasionally, my project spontaneously pops up this warning message:

> May 14 01:24:01 Neovenator-2.local Project[22645] : void
>   CGSUpdateManager::log() const: conn 0x4b29b: spurious update.

And I have no idea how to handle or even interpret it. There's nothing in my project called CGSUpdateManager, and my project doesn't call a log() function anywhere. I can't even reliably reproduce it, but it's popped up often enough to raise my interest level.

Searches at both Google and here for the term "spurious update" reveals a lightly scattered set of conversation, but nothing relevant to my project. Meanwhile, a Google search for "CGSUpdateManager" reveals it's something to do with Swift, which I'm not using at all.

Can anyone help me understand what this means? Or should I just disregard it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to call super in viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear.

Comment: I don't even hook any of those functions, so [super] should be natively called for all of them. The only functions I'm using are applicationDidFinishLaunching and applicationWillTerminate - neither of which has a [super] equivalent that I can call (yes, I tried).

Comment: I see this occasionally as well. I don't have any `viewWillAppear` or `viewWillDisappear` methods. All of my `viewDidLoad` methods call `super viewDidLoad];` before doing anything else.

Comment: I had the warning, and I found (without comments):
`- (void)setNeedsDisplay
{
//#if 1    //TEST (suppose we are only called by us)
    if(wvImageRep_DoRebuild)
//#endif
        [super setNeedsDisplay]; // "spurious update" ?
}`
After I comment the two lines, no more warning. But restoring these don't make the warning sure to appear... 
I think, track every code that would need `super`...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my code with correct Highlight/indentation:

```
- (void)setNeedsDisplay
{
//#if 1    //TEST (suppose we are only called by us)
    if(wvImageRep_DoRebuild)
//#endif
        [super setNeedsDisplay]; // "spurious update" ?
}
```

It's an example (@see my full response), it helped me